# Porting a .jsb3 project to a modern sencha cmd 4.0 compatible project

Tags: mobile, extjs, build, sencha-touch, migration

I have a mobile application crated using sencha touch. The app skeleton was generated by `sencha app generate`. So it contains `app.json`, `app.js` etc files and folders. But as I have a lot of extra js files I used a .jsb3 file to build the project. So right now I build it by

```
sencha build -p /path/to/project.jsb3 -d target/folder/
```

Now I want to make this build system latest Sencha Cmd 4.0 compatible. How do I do it?

Comment: What are those extra js files ? If you `require` them correctly in the application or controllers, they should be included with `sencha app build`. I don't have the experience and don't know if you will run in other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lorenz Meyer points out, you can try to use the "requires" keyword on the relevant classes to include your extra JS code. This assumes the JS files you're talking about adhere to the Sencha class system.

Additionally, Sencha Touch's app.json file has a "js" array you could use - this array loads arbitrary JS resources, even ones which don't adhere to Sencha's class system.

You could also use Sencha Cmd to manually compile the additional resources... but that's an advanced topic and would require detailed knowledge of your code to really offer advice.

If all else fails you can just include these JS files in your index.html, loading them from the /resources/ folder (which gets automatically copied into your build output).

At the end of the day, there's no specific migration path for your case - but the above methods are generally the ways to go.

Answer (score 1):

Another point to think about is that each file should contain one class defined by 'Ext.define' and whose name corresponds to the file path ( e.g. The file in /app/view/Main.js should contain the class AppName.view.Main.
I don't know if this is a prerequisite for using Sencha cmd 4.0 or if it is only recommended.

You should not include the javascript files manually in your HTML, as long as they contain ExtJs code and not plain javascript or third-party scripts. Sencha cmd also compresses the files using YUI compressor and builds the theme css in such a way that it only contains required code.